# Why doesn't this print the array?

Tags: arrays

```
char [] abeceda = {'a' 'b' 'c' 'd' 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h' 'i' 'j' 'k' 'l' 'm' 'n' 'o' 'p' 'q' 'r' 's''t' 'u' 'v' 'w' 'x' 'y' 'z'};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(abeceda));
```

It's pretty simple, idk why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

It was because i didn't put the ","